# Symfony2: 'php app/console assets:install web' triggers error (unvalid yaml)

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

I am just getting started with symfony2. Based on [this](http://blog.quadspot.de/wordpress/symfony2/symfony2-tutorial-part-3-backend-with-sonataadminbundle) tutorial, I am trying to install the Sonato Admin Bundle.

The tutorial instructs me to run the following command after installing the files using composer:

```
php app/console assets:install web
```

This triggers the following error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException]
The file "C:\xampp\htdocs\robot\app/config\config.yml" does not contain val
id YAML in C:\xampp\htdocs\robot\app/config\config.yml (which is being impo
rted from "C:\xampp\htdocs\robot\app/config/config_dev.yml").

[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]
The file "C:\xampp\htdocs\robot\app/config\config.yml" does not contain val
id YAML.

[Symfony\Component\Yaml\Exception\ParseException]
Unable to parse at line 47 (near "    cssrewrite: ~").
```

An error in the config file surprises me, as the app_dev/ version of the site runs fine. In both the production (config_prod.yml) and the dev environment (config_dev.yml), the config.yml is included.

This is line 41-52 of config.yml:

```
# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
filters:        WebProfilerBundle
    cssrewrite: ~
    #closure:
    #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar"
    #yui_css:
    #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"
```

Anyone knows what's going on? If necessary, I can post the full config.yml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a random "WebProfilerBundle" that isn't supposed to be there:

```
    bundles: [ ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
filters:        **WebProfilerBundle**
    cssrewrite: ~
```

Just delete it.

```
    bundles: [ ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
filters:
    cssrewrite: ~
```

Comment: That solves it, thanks. I am not used to the yaml syntax, thanks for pointing me to the issue. Will accept when allowed.

Comment: @dirk I just noticed what the bundle name was. WebProfilerBundle doesn't need to be added to assetic config, so you should just delete it altogether. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I've been messing with the file a lot now, just trying to figure out this framework.

Comment: No problem. I highly recommend the framework. As well as learning composer if you don't already know it so that you can easily use any of it's components in projects that don't use the framework, and other awesome packages in packagist like goutte, facebook-sdk, aws-sdk, guzzle, monolog, doctrine, swiftmailer, lessphp, phpexcel, etc

Comment: @dirk I'm not sure if you're aware of this or not, but Symfony 2.8 and 3.0 were both just released on Monday. They are the same except 3.0 has removed all deprecated features. Since it removed those a lot of bundles have been made incompatible, but as you can see SonataAdminBundle is compatible with Symfony 3.0: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GOxJ2lNpLxN12YyZ87Bhsxb0iLAQ7e4UDZbJSly8Sy8/edit#gid=0